Why does the telegraphs equation not include inductance on the secondary path?
Apologies if I've missed something obvious, but when learning about the derivation for all the equations and behaviour with transmission lines, i noticed for example in the attached image, the bottom line has no modelling of inductance. However i always though that even a non-differential pair like coax will indeed have inductance on the inner part shield? (Given the wave is guided between the center and shield and is not the same voltage along the whole shield at any moment), surely that would require some model of impedance along that line?


George kirby - Hi, Where did that image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More site rules in the [tour] & [help].)

It's because the model is not supposed to literally represent any particular TL line type, but constitute an equivalent lumped element model. Thus the various components represent the total equivalent values for this segment, even if they don't reflect the real distribution of the same in a real segment (the emphasis is on the word equivalent). I was pondering the same question some time ago, but a paragraph in a textbook helped me se this way.


the bottom line has no modeling of inductance. However i always though
that even a non-differential pair like coax will indeed have
inductance on the inner part shield?

An ideal coax cable driven correctly will have a shield inductance of zero. Explanation: -
The current flowing through the inner conductor produces a magnetic field outside the shield that is identical in magnitude (but opposite in sign) to the magnetic field from return current in the shield. Hence, ideally, there is no magnetic field outside the shield.
Also, because the shield is an electrical "tube" it cannot create internal magnetic fields hence, given what I said previously (in italics) and this paragraph, it cannot have inductance.
Taking a wider viewpoint, you can model a balanced t-line like the picture in your question if you want or, you can make it more complex if you want. In other words this: -

Is equivalent to this: -

And, it's also equivalent to this model: -


Appreciate the information as always. But one thing I seem to be confused is the shield inductance, in your paragraph 2 you said th shield produces a field equal in magnetic opposite in sign to the inner wire, yet in paragraph 3 you said the shield is unable to create a magnet field hence no induction? Perhaps I'm reading that wrong? And if there is indeed no inductance, how can there be different voltages also the shield at given points? Many thanks

@Georgekirby I actually said that a tube (the shield) cannot create an internal magnetic field i.e. a field inside the tube. It can create an external field but, that is cancelled by the external field from the inner conductor current. Therefore the shield is not subject to any net field when the coax is driven correctly and has therefore zero net inductance. Of course a non-ideal coax has resistance and this creates a little voltage on the shield than can radiate.

Ill take that at fact. Does this then mean assuming no resistance on the shield. The voltage at any point along the outside shield will always be 0 relative to say the driving signals ground?

@Georgekirby on an ideal coaxial cable that has a grounded drive and a termination resistor that matches the characteristic impedance, yes. Reality doesn't play clean though.

The model just a model and it is a simple model.
It takes everything and assumes the return path is ideal with no resistance or inductance.
So the inductances and other losses are just moved to one place and assumed they all exist on the signal wire.
With a more complex model, you can of course model the return path with separate inductance and resistance for more accurate representation of real world cable.
It's just a good first order model for a cable.
Just like a simple real world resistor is often modeled by simple resistance, even if a real world resistor has inductance on the leads and capacitance between terminals. At DC they may be irrelevant so they don't need modeling, at RF, they may become important and even a first order model with lead inductance and terminal capacitance is not enough.

Without loss of generality, we can model the differential mode as common-ground, taking one line as reference, whether twin lead or coax. The voltage drop along a given line doesn't matter, as we take each port as the voltage difference at a particular point along the line.
More generally, we can separate the system into two parts: the differential and common mode aspects, which in general will have two different equivalent circuits (or, well, for the infinitesimal version, the circuit doesn't matter, but the values differ).  We can employ both, when we measure both lines with respect to some other reference.  This is important for differential signaling, telephony, EMC, etc., where the common mode is relevant.
